# MongoDB: Count of matching nested array elements

Tags: mongodb

I've got a simple parent child object stored as a document in MongoDB.  Something simplistic like Order/OrderItems.  (Order has an array of OrderItem)

What I'd like to do is query for a count of Order Items where they meet a set of criteria.

Example: In Order "999" find out how many order items had a quantity of 3.

```
db.collection.find( {OrderId:999, "OrderItems.QuantityOrdered":3} ).count();
```

The way this query works is it returns "1" because if it matches at least one OrderItem inside the array it will return the count of Orders matched.

How can I query for how many "OrderItems" matched?:

Comment: Seems to work for me. Unless I have the structure incorrectly.

> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c2e2c7bd39925311b1edae7"), "orderid" : 1, "orderitems" : { "quantityordered" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c2e2c8ad39925311b1edae8"), "orderid" : 1, "orderitems" : { "quantityordered" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c2e2c93d39925311b1edae9"), "orderid" : 1, "orderitems" : { "quantityordered" : 3 } }
>

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way of return this sort of count with an embedded document. With this sort of ad-hoc count, your best bet is to return the document and do the count from the application.

If you want to perform this kind of count for a large number of orders, you could use map-reduce, which will output the results to a new collection.

Comment: I agree. However, if you need that kind of data often, the most promoted approach is to store the count in the document itself and update it accordingly on the application side.