# Count array documents in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a entity collection like this:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f93cedc4fd0e1f309aea64"),
        "entityType" : "1",
        "identifierIdentity" : [
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI",
                        "identifierValue" : "111"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI",
                        "identifierValue" : "123"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI",
                        "identifierValue" : "141"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "SSN",
                        "identifierValue" : "155"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f93cedc4fd0e1f309aea65"),
        "entityType" : "2",
        "identifierIdentity" : [
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI",
                        "identifierValue" : "111"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI",
                        "identifierValue" : "123"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "SSN",
                        "identifierValue" : "155"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f93cedc4fd0e1f309aea66"),
        "entityType" : "3",
        "identifierIdentity" : [
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "SSN",
                        "identifierValue" : "111"
                },
                {
                        "identifierTypeCode" : "SSN",
                        "identifierValue" : "123"
                }
        ]
}
```

in the above identifierIdentity is an array of documents.

I am trying to get the entity count where "identifierTypeCode" : "NPI" is greater than or equal to two.

I am able to get this using java code but i have millions of records which is taking a lot of time. I want to know whether is their a way i can achieve this in a single query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongo - get documents with nested objects matching count condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484001/mongo-get-documents-with-nested-objects-matching-count-condition)

Answer (score 0):

The [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) aggregate operator will make short work of this, coupled with a match for arrays that have at least two elements to trim thngs down:

```js
    db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "identifierIdentity.identifierTypeCode": "NPI",
        "identifierIdentity.1": { "$exists": true }
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { 
                "$gte":  [ 
                    { "$size": { "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$identifierIdentity",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": {
                                    "if": { "$eq": ["$$el.identifierTypeCode", "NPI"] },
                                    "then": "$$el",
                                    "else": false
                                }
                            }
                        }},
                        [false]
                    ] } },
                    2
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

Basically match first to cut down the possible documents to procces, the the `$redact` does another logical match by filtering out the matches from the array and counting the size of the result. Where greater or equal to 2, then you keep the result, or otherwise discard it.

Comment: i am getting an error message as invalid operator $gte

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli Typo. There was a trailing space.